# How to CSS style AngularJS directive?

Tags: css, angularjs

Assuming I have a directive "mydirect" with a template that contains a lot of divs with a lot of nested classes. For example:

```
<div class="mydirect">
  <div class="classA">
    <div class="subclassA">
      <div class="subclassB">
      </div>
    <div class="classB"></div>
</div>
```

I noticed that despite having the classnames in a css file ("mydirectstyle.css") and it being included in index.html, using my directive:

```
angular.module("MyApp", []).
  directive('mydirect', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: '-All that Html here-'
    };
  });
```

None of the CSS properties are applied to it whatsoever. What is the best way to apply all my styles to those multiple classes? Can it be done such that I don't have to manually select each element and set individual CSS properties?

My index.html page contains a `<mydirect> </mydirect>` that gets replaced by the directive template shown above.

Comment: the css properties should apply in your directive template.  Can you make a plunker or jsfiddle which shows the problem?

Comment: Yep, hard to tell you what's going on without seeing your CSS

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Its much easier to use actual element names to create directives in your DOM rather than trying to use the class method.  For two reasons: 1) its much more readable to have `<mydirect>` vs `<div class="mydirect">` and 2) you can get the same ease of styling by just using the proper css syntax.

Leave your directive just the way it is, except change it to `restrict: 'EA'` (docs for that [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#template-expanding-directive)) and `replace: false`, as shown here:

```
.directive('mydirect', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: false,
        template: '-All that Html here-'
    };
});
```

Here are the options you can now use and how to configure the corresponding CSS to get the styles you want, as shown in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xeqicuqalu/edit?html,css,output):

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: You have `replace: true` enabled with a template, so your component element gets replaced with a `<p>` tag (based on your template string). Therefore the CSS of `hello-world{...}` doesn't match and therefore doesn't get applied. If you set `replace: false`, everything works.

Comment: You are correct. To avoid confusion, I have updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

**Angular Directive with Custom CSS.**

```js
app.directive('bookslist', function() {

    return {
     scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/bookslist.html',
        restrict: "E",
        controller: function($scope){

        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes){
        element.addClass('customClass');
      }

    }

});
```

```css
.customClass table{
 !background: #ddd;

}
.customClass td{
 border: 1px solid #ddd;

}
```

Comment: A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Furthermore, the snippet does not run.

Answer (score 4):

As per google under and Angular directive creation logic  In below example’s description object, setting two config components. First, we’re setting the restrict config option. The restrict option is used to specify how a directive can be invoked on the page.

As we saw before, there are four different ways to invoke a directive, so there are four valid options for restrict:

```
'A' - <span ng-sparkline></span> 
'E' - <ng-sparkline></ng-sparkline> 
'C' - <span class="ng-sparkline"></span> 
'M' - <!-- directive: ng-sparkline -->
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution to this is simple. But its only a guess.
You define the directive by using:

```
<div class="mydirect></div>
```

and in your directive definition you use:

```
restrict: 'E'
```

The directive is not rendered by Angularjs because Angularjs is looking for something like:

```
<mydirect></mydirect>
```

Simply change `restrict: 'E'` to `restrict: 'C'`.

Comment: I tried that. it doesn't work. it must have something to do with the fact the my direct element when replaced by the directive template , none of the CSS gets applied because of the replacement. question is how to deal with it?

Comment: @Rolando here is an example that seems to work in the way you describe; perhaps something else is amiss.  Do note however that the directive class is applied to the template itself, so your classes might not be ending up where you expect them. http://plnkr.co/edit/zQ5teYoQ7qeUbsM71b57

Comment: @Rolando how do you call your directive? you need to have <div class=mydirect></div> somewhere outside of the directive "mydirect" template. I think the problem is not the replacement but the fact that angularjs doesn't find the directive to render.